# How to link fixed choices to new created questions in django

Tags: python, django, model, m2m

I'm very new as a django developer and I'm attempting to build a ranking web app.
What I wanted to do is once a new question is created by the user through a crispy form, automatically changed the m2m model and link that new question with the choices. The choices are a fixed rank from 1 to 5 and they cannot be manipulated by users and not showing on the question create form.

From what I read, I guess that this operation could be done by m2m_changed signal (or post_save, not sure), but I'm not really familiar with its functionality. I tried several times on differents ways but I'm not addresing good results. When I go to the admin page and set the choices to the new question manually this works perfect; same thing when I create the question and run the for loop by command line through the shell, but what I want is automate this process when the question is created by users.
Sorry for the extensive, hope to be clearly enough!
Thanks for the help!!
I breakdown my codes below.

### models.py

```
class Choice(models.Model):
choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)

def __str__(self):
    return self.choice_text


class Question(models.Model):
choice = models.ManyToManyField(Choice)
question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
pub_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
client = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

def __str__(self):
    return self.question_text

def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('dashboard:detail',kwargs={'pk':self.pk})
```

### signals.py

```
@receiver(m2m_changed, sender=Question.choice.through)
def update_question_model(sender, instance, **kwargs):

instance = kwargs.pop('instance', None)
choice_set = Choice.objects.all().values_list('pk',flat=True)
for i in choice_set:
    c = Choice.objects.get(pk=i)
    instance.choice.add(c)
    instance.save()

m2m_changed.connect(update_question_model, sender=Question.choice.through)
```

### views.py

```
class ConsignaCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
model = Question
fields = ['question_text']

def form_valid(self, form):
    form.instance.client = self.request.user
    return super().form_valid(form)
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found a way to do this with post_save signal.
In case of this helps for anyone, I breakdown the code.

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=Question)
def update_question_model(sender, instance, **kwargs):
q = Question.objects.get(pk=instance.pk)
choice_set = Choice.objects.all().values_list('pk', flat=True)
for i in choice_set:
    c = Choice.objects.get(pk=i)
    q.choice.add(c)
    post_save.disconnect(update_question_model, sender=Question)
    q.save()
    post_save.connect(update_question_model, sender=Question)
```

I'm still wondering if this can be done in a simplier way with m2m_changed signal??